# Creating HTML form using XML to define layout C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5

I have some XML in the following schema:

```
<Form ID="1" Formtitle="Title">
    <Fields>
            <Fieldset Legend="LegendText" >
                <Field FieldName="Field1" Label="Title" Type="Text" Required="1" />
                <Field FieldName="Field2" Label="Radio" Type="Radio" Required="0">
                    <Option Value="1" Text="Just One"/>
                    <Option Value="2" Text="Maybe Two"/>
                </Field>
            </Fieldset>
    </Fields>
</Form>
```

I need to parse through this in C# to generate a HTML form that would represent the following:

```
<h1>Formtitle</h1>
<form id="1" action="myurl.com">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>LegendText</legend>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="Field1" class="jqueryValidate"/>
        <!-- jqueryvalidate class added as required is equal to 1 in XML -->
        <label>Radio</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Field2" Value="1"/> Just One
        <input type="radio" name="Field2" Value="2"/> Maybe Two
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now, I am aware that I can achieve the same kind of thing using XSLT, however I must use C# here as I will be wrapping this up into a control that I can drop in to any of my pages.

My question is, how could I acheive something like this? I envisage it requiring some type of nested switch statements to check node names and types etc, and stringbuilding the HTML. But, I'm hoping this isn't the case, and you boffins can help point me in the right direction with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Dave

Comment: I suspect LINQ to XML or similar would enable a more concise solution if XSLT is not an option.

Comment: You can use XSLT in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to devise some objects that represent the various HTML entities that you want to generate.  Note, this is a very, very simplified example.  You could have a base class with all kinds of trickery and reusability in it.  But that's out of the scope of the question and we'd both be here all day :)

```
public interface IElement
{
    string RenderStart();
    string RenderEnd();
    string Render();
    IList<IElement> Children { get; }
    void LoadFromXML(XmLReader reader);
}  // eo interface IElement


public abstract class Element : IElement
{
    List<IElement> children_ = new List<IElement>();

    public List<IElement> Children { get { return children_; } }

    public string Render()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(RenderStartTag());
        foreach(IElement e in children_)
            builder.Append(e.Render());
        builder.Append(RenderEndTag());
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}  // eo class Element


public class FieldSetElement : Element
{
    public string RenderStart()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<fieldset legend=\"")
               .Append("\">");
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public string RenderEnd()
    {
        return ("</fieldset>");
    }

    public string Legend {get; set; }

    public void LoadFromXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Legend = reader.GetAttribute("legend");
    } // eo LoadFromXml
}  // eo class FieldSet
```

Obviously, you'd have an `Element` derived class for each HTML element.  We also have a way of having them initialised from an Xml node.  But now, we need to associate our Xml tags with our DOM objects.  We can do that using a dictionary (in this simple case.  I'd prefer a full blown factory, but again - that's outside the scope of this answer!)

```
public delegate IElement ElementCreator;
Dictionary<string, ElementCreator> creators_ = new Dictionary<string, ElementCreator>
```

I'll go ahead and add the one for our `FieldSet` element:

```
creators_["fieldset"] = () => { return new FieldSet(); };
// and so on for other creators and elements.
```

Ok!  We're almost there.  Next step is to to translate that XML document in to objects.  I'll presume at this point we'd have some kind of a root object.  I'm going to call that `Html` (surprising name!).  As you can guess, it also derives from `Element`.  It's going to act as our root node.

```
Html root = new Html();
```

Now, we'll need a function to read the Xml in and translate it in to our current parent.

```
XmlReader reader = new XmlReader("layout.xml");
Stack<IElement> currentRoot = new Stack<IElement>();
currentRoot.Push(root);
while(reader.Read())
{
    // get the element tag
    if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
       Debug.Assert(creators_.ContainsKey(reader.Name));  // must have it!
       IElement newElement = creators_[reader.Name].Invoke(); // create it
       newElement.LoadFromXml(reader);            // tell element to read itself in
       currentRoot.Peek().Children.Add(newElement); // add to parent
       currentRoot.Push(newElement);  // we are now new parent
    }
    else if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
       currentRoot.Pop();  // just pop it off!
}
```

Wow!  We're practically done.  At this point, we have a collection of objects!  All that remains is to render them.

```
string html = root.Render();
```

BAM.  We're done.

Sorry if there are any errors in the code, I'll try and go over it.  I have not run this, but I have done something similar before.  I'm also not suggesting this is the best way, I am sure there are others.  This is *one* way.  I've left out the rendering of attributes for reasons of brevity, but I'll be happy to add another concrete `Element` example to show how that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to confirm your fears, but there is no "generic" or "simplistic" way to do this.

As you mentioned, XSLT is the standard practice, failing which you would need to build some sort of custom parser / string builder which does the same thing.

One approach that does come to mind is using a MVC framework to lessen your workload.

MVC frameworks come with 'autobinder' like functionality which basically takes any class and generates the appropriate HTML (using which ever view engine).

So if you chose that route, your task will be limited to simple parsing XML and created well formed, annotation decorated classes. The MVC framework will then be able to generate all CRUD views for you in HTML.

Hope that helps, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how averse you are to using XSLT but you can achieve this by using XSLT in C# with the following.

```
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace XmlTransform
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load the style sheet.
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslt.Load(@"C:\style.xsl");

            // Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
            xslt.Transform(@"C:\input.xml", @"C:\result.html");
            Console.WriteLine("Result saved to C:\result.html");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Where the input.xml file is what you stated in your original question and the style.xsl looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/Form">
<html>
<body>
<h1><xsl:value-of select="@Formtitle"/></h1>
<form id="1" action="myurl.com">
<fieldset>
    <legend><xsl:value-of select="Fields/Fieldset/@Legend"/></legend>
<label>Title</label>
<xsl:for-each select="Fields/Fieldset/Field">
<xsl:if test="@Type = 'Text'">      
<xsl:if test="@Required='1'">
<input type="text" name="{@FieldName}" class="jqueryValidate"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@Required='0'">
<input type="text" name="{@FieldName}"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="@Type = 'Radio'">
<xsl:if test="@Required='1'">
<label><xsl:value-of select="@Label"/></label>
<input type="radio" name="{FieldName}"/>" class="jqueryValidate"/>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="@Required='0'">
<label><xsl:value-of select="@Label"/></label>
<xsl:for-each select="Option">
<input type="radio" name="Field2" Value="1"/> Just One
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Good Luck!